# What is the pythonic way to instantiate a program based on a class

Tags: python

I have the following program:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def hello(self):
        print ("hello")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = MyClass()
    a.hello()
```

It could also be launched as

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hello()
    def hello(self):
        print ("hello")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyClass()
```

Is there a reason to prefer one style over the other, python wise (outside of personal preferences)? In other words: is there a advantage/disadvantage to handle the program general flow and logic within `__init__` vs. having that flow outside of the class?

The code is intended to run as a standalone script, pretty much like in the examples above, just more complicated.

Comment: Why use a class for this at all?

Comment: The latter is semantically wrong, because the constructor is not supposed to do any extra work apart, well, initializing the object. If you really want to avoid an extra line, you can use `MyClass().hello()`.

Comment: @user2357112: why not? The program is obviously more complicated, with `self` variables referenced between the functions (among others)

Comment: See [Stop Writing Classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0).

Comment: If you have to call `pass` in `init`, it shouldn't be a class... ( @unutbu - I was trying to find that video :-p ) Also, [Code Like a Pythonista: Idiomatic Python](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html)

Comment: If you use `__init__` as your program's `main`, you can only ever reasonably make one instance of your class, and it won't be fully constructed until your program is done. That sounds like a misuse of the class system.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl: this is just an example. I see I should have posted the whole 400 lines and not reduce them to a working example (just kidding) :)

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I disagree with that. An object can have state without needing to initialize anything on object creation. Unless of course you meant that the method just shouldn’t be defined when passing anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've invented another example that shows the motivation for having a class at all, in your second style. Obviously this is massively over-engineered for what it does. Let's just suppose that aside from your call, there's some other code somewhere that will use the class to do something other than just call one function, so that this complex interface is justified.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.get_config()
        self.validate_config()
        self.hello()
    def get_config(self):
        self.message = "hello"
    def validate_config(self):
        # I'm not claiming this is good practice, just
        # an example of multiple methods that share state
        if not self.message:
            raise Exception()
    def hello(self):
        print(self.message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyClass()
```

So what do we have here? Basically you're using the call to `MyClass` not for the purpose of creating an object (although it does do that and you discard it), but in order to execute the object's `__init__` method. It works, of course, but it's not "natural". The natural thing is that if you want to run "some stuff" you call a function containing the stuff. You don't especially want it to return some object you don't even care about. If the stuff needs to maintain some state to do its work then the function can handle that, you don't need it to show you the state at the end:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.get_config()
        self.validate_config()
    def get_config(self):
        self.message = "hello"
    def validate_config(self):
        # I'm not claiming this is good practice, just
        # an example of multiple methods that share state
        if not self.message:
            raise Exception()
    def hello(self):
        print(self.message)

def main():
    MyClass().hello()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This looks more like your first style than your second, so in that sense I prefer the first.

Having a `main` function might make it a tiny bit easier to use your module under some kind of harness, like a Python prompt or a test harness. It's not necessary, though. If someone wants to do the same as happens when `__name__ == '__main__'` then worst case they can copy that source.

Answer (score 1):

You can always ask yourself: Is this still the behaviour I want if I instantiate 100 instances of this class?

It is tempting to load everything this object is supposed to do into a single method such as **init**(self), to make the main method as short as possible. As long as this stays your private script, there is no point in preferring one over the other.

However, once the code is shared, or the class is imported by another script, you increase the reusability by making **init**() only execute a few necessary initialization commands.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate your example is only to illustrate your point, and not because you want to print "hello" and need a class to do so ;)

The `if __name__ == "__main__":` in the file suggests that the file is also suitable for importing.  Do you want the class to always print "hello" when instantiated?  Normally, behavior is in methods and the `__init__` only contains initialization.

Comment: Yes, this is the minimum code to illustrate my question :) I always put the `if __name__ == "__main__":`condition in my code, mostly to visually segregate the actual program - even if no import is planned later.

Comment: @WoJ right, so stuff that initialises the class - including code you want to put in methods for tidiness sake - go in the constructor, and its behaviour goes in methods that others call on it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you solve different things here. Usually, the purpose of creating an object is not to have it fire off something and then disappear (that’s more a function’s job). Instead, you usually want to object to stay around, and interact with it. As such, you would definitely want to save the object reference in a variable:

```
obj = MyClass()
```

Next, you should think about if something should *always* be called *whenever an object is created*. If that’s the case, then yes, you probably should put that into the `__init__`. If it is not true for even just a minor case, then you should probably separate it to make it possible to do initialization and that action separately.

Your example is obviously just very simple so it doesn’t make much sense in the first place. But usually, I would see `hello` as a public API which I would likely to call when having an object of that type. On the other hand, I wouldn’t expect it to be called automatically just when I create the object.

There might be cases where something like this is useful and desired, but in general, you would prefer calling the method explicitely.